# Facebook app- getting name of a user doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook

I'm creating a Facebook app with the PHP SDK 3.2.0 and I encountered a problem. When I'm making an API call, trying to get name of a user nothing occours. I'm using the example from github.com and still can't achieve what I'm loking for.

```
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you authenticated the user and requested the basic permissions?

Comment: I believe there is no need to request permission for name or last name as the users basic informations are public. At least that's what Facebook says.

Comment: Well you are most certainly wrong my friend. As far as applications go, **without authentication and basic permissions, an application doesn't know who is viewing it.** There are differences with privacy when viewing Facebook as a user and viewing data from the API with an application.

Comment: In that case, can I request the basic permissions via authenticated referrals or should I somehow do it in php?

Comment: I haven't used these authenticated referrals... But I don't see why not! =)

Comment: If you have other proven way to do it, I would be more than happy to use it, as I had tried to use authenticated referrals before and they are a bit troublemaking

Comment: "Nothing occurs" Well _something_ occurs when you run your code. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to verify first if you have an active access token. If not you should show the Facebook login button.

```
<?php
$userId = $facebook -> getUser();

 if ($userId) { 
  $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' . $userId); ?>
  Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>   
<?php } ?>
```

According to your code it should be like this:

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
));
?>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'http://YOURDOMAIN.com/channel.php', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
      //alert(me.name);
    });
    }
</script>


<?php
$userId = $facebook -> getUser();

if ($userId) { 
  $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' . $userId); ?>
  Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>   
<?php } ?>

    <script>
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        ( function(d) {
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                    return;
                }
                js = d.createElement('script');
                js.id = id;
                js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
            }(document));
    </script>
```

You should have a channel.php file in your server, that would have the following content:

```
<?php
$cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
?>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly should I put it?

Comment: Edited my answer, and added a variable that I forgot before.

Comment: I just tried that and there's still no effect, complately blank page. I guess there's still something missing.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but unfortunately it still doesn't work... I think I have just lost all the faith for it to ever start working.

Comment: Very strange. Do you have it online? Do you have created the channel.php file? Did you changed the App id (in two places in the code) and the App secret? Is the link referencing the facebook library in the correct place? Is the app in the Fb developers correctly configured? Is the domain allowed?

Comment: The answer to all od this quesions is yes. But what's interesting is that it works perfectly without 

<?php
$userId = $facebook -> getUser();

if ($userId) { 
  $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' . $userId); ?>
  Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>   
<?php } ?>

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by it works perfectly? As long as you don't get the username, it is not working. The code I've been checking with you, supposedly, would let me login in and create a new token so you could then use the public data from Facebook.

Comment: I'm able to get profile pic with "XXX is currently using  XApp" but whenever I want to retrieve any data with $userId = $facebook -> getUser(); everything immediately stops working.

Comment: Very strange. Do you have your Facebook PHP SDK updated? Do you have it online? Maybe you could post your entire code please?

Answer (score 1):

Authenticated Referrals are deprecated and will be removed in February 2013.

That being said, i recommend using FB.login for user login:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

If you don´t want to use the Javascript SDK, there is also an easier way with the PHP SDK:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

Everything is explained well in the docs. Just some more lines of code for you.